# password generator without repetition google sheets script editor

Tags: javascript

I have a code that generates a string of 6 characters, this code generates 3 different characters and 3-digital number in the column
I would like this code to check in this column cell by cell whether the values ​​generated by this generator are unique (they are not repeated). If he finds repetitive value ​​in the cell, I want to generate the value for the cell again.
Thank you in advance for your help

```js
// index.gs

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Indexe Master Babe").addItem('Insert that SHIT', 'insertData').addToUi(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
}
indexService.gs

function insertData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var coordinates = getCoordinatesToStart(sheet);

  if (coordinates) {

    var indexArray = prepareIndexArray(); //geting two demension array of indexes
    sheet.getRange(coordinates.row, coordinates.column, indexArray.length, 1).setValues(indexArray); // get range from marked cell to array.length cells

  } else {
    showAlert();
  }

}

function getCoordinatesToStart(sheet) {
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  if (isZeroSafe(row) || isZeroSafe(column)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return {
      row: row,
      column: column
    };
  }
}

function prepareIndexArray() {
  var array = [];
  var takenStrings = [];
  var index = "";
  var blankSpace = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var indexString = getRandomIndexString();

    while (takenStrings.indexOf(indexString) !== -1) {
      var indexString = getRandomIndexString();
    }

    takenStrings.push(indexString);

    index = indexString + getIndexNumber(i);

    array.push([index]);
  };

  return array;
}

function getRandomIndexString() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
};

function getIndexNumber(i) {
  var indexNumber = "";

  var blankSpace = 3 - getIntegerLength(i);

  for (var zeroCount = 0; zeroCount < blankSpace; zeroCount++) {
    indexNumber += "0";
  };

  indexNumber += i;
  return indexNumber;
}


function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.alert(
    'Please click on any Cell',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}




// utilities.gs


function isNull(input) {
  return input === null;
}

function isUndefinded(input) {
  return input === undefined;
}

function isZero(input) {
  return input === 0;
}

function isZeroSafe(input) {
  return isUndefinded(input) || isNull(input) || isZero(input)
}

function getIntegerLength(number) {
  var stringHelper = number + "";
  return stringHelper.length;
}
```

Comment: Hmm hellow there :) Assuming you still want help please tell us what you tried and why it doesn't work / What's the error.

Comment: I have a code in excel vba that does what I want to do

Comment: If RowNum > NumPasswordsToCompare Then
            For x = RowNum - 1 To RowNum - NumPasswordsToCompare Step -1
                If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = Password Then
                    GoTo GeneratePassword
                End If
            Next x
        Else
            For x = 1 To RowNum - 1
                If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = Password Then
                    GoTo GeneratePassword
                End If
            Next x
        End If

Comment: something like that i need

Comment: I tried redo this code to javascript but i don't know how to replace goto because  javascript doesn't supports goto